# Importing bitbucket to gitlab failing due to Import failed due to a BitBucket Server error: execution expired error

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I m trying to migrate bitbucket project to gitlab. For this I m trying to use following [gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/import.html),

Rest API: **/api/v4/import/bitbucket_server**

Payload:

```
{
    "bitbucket_server_url": "http://13.37.65.138:7990",
    "bitbucket_server_username": "user1",
    "bitbucket_server_project": "TEST",
    "bitbucket_server_repo": "test-repo",
    "target_namespace": "TEST",
    "personal_access_token": "<personalaccesstokenvalue>"
}
```

Here user1 has admin access to TEST project in bitbucket. I m using admin account to access gitlab api.

But I m getting an error response as below,
Response Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Response Payload:

```
{
    "message": {
        "error": "Import failed due to a BitBucket Server error: execution expired"
    }
}
```

I tried to import the bitbucket project from the UI option provided by Gitlab, but still getting the same error on UI as well

[image]

I tried accessing other Bitbucket Rest API to check for any connectivity issue but I m getting success response.

I also rechecked the [prerequisites](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/bitbucket_server.html#import-your-bitbucket-repositories) for migration from bitbucket to gitlab and its all good.

Can someone please help me with this? Is there anything I m missing here? Please guide me with any solution or workaround here. I want to migrate a bitbucket project into gitlab.

Comment: workaround? Sure! Use a local repo, setup the bitbucket and gitlab repos as _remotes_, then push stuff from one remote into the other (it's not a _single step_ thing, for sure, but it should not be very complex).